# How can I find which decryption algorithm was used on a hash?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography

I have this hash that I need to decipher for testing purposes:

```
$2b$10$b/1hKpwXRK99TYz/mNKp3OqQ59TA3ji8rSYhWszhRm9CS/COzcex6
```

How can I find which algorithm is this hash created with ?

Is there any reliable tool online ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where 2x prefix are used in BCrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733196/where-2x-prefix-are-used-in-bcrypt)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the scheme that indicates how these password hash strings are build up [in the Wikipedia article of `crypt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)), but is misses the 2b variant. A somewhat more specific one can be found [in the documentation of passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html#os-defined-hashes). But the full explanation of *bcrypt variant `2b`* can be found right [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36225192/589259).

By the way, password hashing is one way; you can only verify passwords against the value, you cannot decipher or decrypt it; the only thing you can do is try to guess the passwords (which the function is explicitly designed to protect against, but if you have enough information about the password it may be doable).